# How this code works, Buffer() understanding

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is task on one site, where you can solve them and then see how other people solved it. One solution is very small and I don't get it.

task: Given two cells on the standard chess board, determine whether they have the same color or not.

For `cell1 = "A1"` and `cell2 = "C3"`, the output should be 
`chessBoardCellColor(cell1, cell2) = true`.

[image: true example]

guys solution to it:
which I want to understand. Especialy this arrow function B.

```
B = s => (Buffer(s)[0] - s[1])%2
chessBoardCellColor = (a,b) => B(a) == B(b)
```

`ChessBoardCellColor` predefined name for function which get call, so return of this function is the answer

Comment: please add the full code sample

Comment: @silver This is it, a two lines all that there is

Comment: [Here is the docs for Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_array) (note that the way it is called here is deprecated, it should be `Buffer.from(s)`).  For ascii ranged chars `Buffer.from(String)[0]` is almost equivalent to call `String.charCodeAt(0)`. I guess you can find how the rest works from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using the Buffer you're creating a matrix that each cell has a value and the cell next to it must have a different result when performing the % operation on it.

if the first cell % 2 result is 1 the 2 cells next to it will have the result of 0 because the change of the Buffer is higher by 1 in the letter or 1 in the number.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer function creates binary representation of string wich it gets.

> Just `Buffer()` is deprecated, node docs suggest using
>   `Buffer.from` instead

For example

```
Buffer('A1') = <Buffer 41 31>
Buffer('A2') = <Buffer 41 32>
```

the difference between char (`A`) converted into buffer and number (`'A2'[1] = 2`) is 63

```
> Buffer.from('A1');
<Buffer 41 31>
> Buffer.from('A1')[0]; // this get us charCodeAt code
65
```

for example B2 code from buffer and with charCodeAt function

```
> 'B2'.charCodeAt(0);
66
> Buffer.from('B2')[0];
66
```

with 'A2' as input arrow function B will return `63 % 2 = 1`

```
 >Buffer.from('A2')[0] -'A2'[1];
 63
```

with 'A1' as input arrow function B will return `64 % 2 = 0`

```
> Buffer.from('A1')[0] -'A1'[1];
64
```

this ones are unequal so the answer is `false`